# Change multiple columns based on condition in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

Here is my sample dataset

```
dat <- data.frame(role1= c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 ,0 , 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
                           0, 0, 0, 1),
                  role2= c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 ,0 , 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
                           1, 0, 0, 1),
                  role3= c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ,0 , 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
                           1, 1, 1, 1))
```

I would like to code that if role 1-3 are all '0' then change role 1-3 to '-97'. This is the way I was able to achieve it. However I am looking for a more efficient way to code this since my dataset has many more than just 3 columns to check.

```
dat$role1[dat$role1==0 & dat$role2==0 & dat$role3==1] <- -97
dat$role2[dat$role1==-97 & dat$role2==0 & dat$role3==1] <- -97
dat$role3[dat$role1==-97 & dat$role2==-97 & dat$role3==1] <- -97
```

Here is what I am hoping to get:

```
  role1 role2 role3
1      1     1     0
2      1     1     0
3      1     1     0
4      1     1     1
5    -97   -97   -97
6    -97   -97   -97
7    -97   -97   -97
8      1     1     1
9      1     1     0
10   -97   -97   -97
11   -97   -97   -97
12   -97   -97   -97
13     1     1     1
14     0     1     1
15     0     0     1
16     0     0     1
17     1     1     1
```

Any help is appreciated - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` option (since that is one of your question tags):

```
library(dplyr)

dat |>  
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ ifelse(all(c_across(everything()) == 0), -97, .))) |>
  ungroup()
```

Or using `rowSums`:

```r
library(dplyr)


dat |>
  mutate(across(starts_with("role"), ~ ifelse(rowSums(pick(starts_with("role"))) == 0, -97, .)))
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `rowSums`:

```r
dat[rowSums(dat == 0) == ncol(dat), ] <- -97

#    role1 role2 role3
# 1      1     1     0
# 2      1     1     0
# 3      1     1     0
# 4      1     1     1
# 5    -97   -97   -97
# 6    -97   -97   -97
# 7    -97   -97   -97
# 8      1     1     1
# 9      1     1     0
# 10   -97   -97   -97
# 11   -97   -97   -97
# 12   -97   -97   -97
# 13     1     1     1
# 14     0     1     1
# 15     0     0     1
# 16     0     0     1
# 17     1     1     1
```